# regex match for string with \\'

Tags: regex

I need to match the rest of the strings in a file. I can match the following:

```
(2, \\'username\\',
```

with

```
^\(\d+,\s\\{2}\'(\w+)\\{2}\',
```

and yield `username` in my capture group. However, I have been unable to extend that regex to capture

```
(2, \\'username\\', \\'pas$word\\', 2, \\'Name\\', \\'Name\\', \\'me@example.biz\\', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, TRUE, 9, FALSE),
```

I tried the optimistic

```
^\(\d+,\s\\{2}\'(\w+)\\{2}\',.*
```

and thinking it something to do with the additional `\\'`, I even tried

```
^\(\d+,\s\\{2}\'(\w+)\\{2}\', [\w\d\s\\,)@.$']*\),
```

but I can't even get these to match on

```
(2, \\'username\\', 'pas$word', 2, 'Name', 'Name', 'me@example.biz', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, TRUE, 9, FALSE),
```

so clearly, I'm missing what's right in front of me.

Comment: [`\d+,\s*\\{2}\'(\S+)\\{2}\',`](https://regex101.com/r/jV3xA3/1)? Or do you intend to match *the whole* strings you provided?

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. I should have put in `\w+`, not `username`, but `\S+` is cleaner. However, I still am not able to match on the longer line. https://regex101.com/r/uY5bG8/1

Comment: Your question lacks exact requirements or at least the expected output per a given sample input. Why do you use`^` anchor? Why should it be followed with `(`? Your question is just unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will capture each string within the line when a value starting with `\\'` and ending with `\\'` is seen.

**RegEx**

```
\\{2}(\'\S*)\\{2}\'
```

Comment: and throwing in the match at the front of the line yields the first such sought string. https://regex101.com/r/uY5bG8/2. So it appears that the real difference between your successful cast and mine is that you did not use the anchor `^` for the beginning of the line. I am not certain why that should break in mine.